# How can i match float? from users to txt

Tags: python, matching

i have a txt file. This txt file has 6 columns and maybe thousands lines. I want to add an input. User writes 2 numbers and they are RA and DEC. My text file has a lot of ra and dec values. (I also share this txt) If it matched, this code will write TIC column. How can i do this matching process on python? I need really help. I can't find anything about this topic.
For example to my algorithm:

```
TIC      CCD    CAMERA  RA         DEC
344356    1       4     324.456    -48.478
356456    1       4     321.275    -46.257
inputs from users: RA:324.456
                   DEC: -48.478
I want to this outputs:
                      TIC:344356
```

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file into a DataFrame and index that with a logical vector of the comparison results:

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv('txt', delimiter='\s+', dtype=str)
RA = input('RA:').strip()
DEC = input('DEC:').strip()
print('TIC:'+','.join(df[(df['RA'] == RA) & (df['DEC'] == DEC)]['TIC']))
```